# CYPRESS - Finding and yielding a table row that contains some text

Tags: javascript, cypress

Im trying to get the entire row that contains some text in the child elements. I want to later manipulate it but when I try:

```
cy.get('.tr').contains('Example Text')
```

... it always yields/returns the span element. I'd like to point to the div of a "tr" class which contains the text. (I've tried using parent() but then it's 2 elements down so using parent().parent() is not the solution I'm guessing).

e.g. code

```
<div class="tr">
    <div class="something">
        <span>Example Text</span>
    <div class="something-else">
<div class="tr">
<div class="tr">
<div class="tr">
<div class="tr">
<div class="tr">
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try inverting/reversing your logic.

Get the element with the text, and then its tr parent:

```
cy.contains('Example Text').parent('.tr');
```

Comment: That works - I didn't know I could pass arguments to parents(). (except for the fact that I had to change parent to parents). Thank you for the answer.